# Expressing "seminal paper"

Tags: usage, citations, académique

**Article fondateur** renders the meaning of *seminal paper* as given here:

https://www.seslisozluk.net/en/what-is-the-meaning-of-seminal-paper/

> Definition of seminal paper in English English dictionary: A seminal paper is a kind of "classic" in a broad meaning of the term. It is a paper which has served as a model for other papers, which first has presented an influential view of theory.

Can we also use **papier fondateur** instead?

For the sake of completeness (merci @aCOSwt):

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68148/when-to-refer-to-a-paper-as-seminal

Comment: What are you doing in a turkish dict ? I'd advise you to read that first : https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68148/when-to-refer-to-a-paper-as-seminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Générique, qui est relatif à la naissance de l’œuvre :  *[Article générique](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=article%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carticle%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique%3B%2Cc0)*

— *Complément, suite au commentaire* —

Dans le cas d’une publication *article fondateur* est plus approprié si l’œuvre influence tout son domaine de référence.

— *Complément, suite à la réponse de LPH* —

Pour un article prépondérant et non originel :

· *Article fondateur de l’évolution* de la théorie de …

· *Article référent des vérifications* de la théorie de …

Comment: Merci, cependant https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=article+g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique%2C+article+fondateur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carticle%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carticle%20fondateur%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

*Larousse en ligne* a une proposition que je trouve utile, si imparfaite : [*majeur ou qui fait école*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/seminal/610563) ([faire école](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9cole/27609/locution?q=faire%20%C3%A9cole#161920)) pour *seminal*. On demande par ailleurs si on peut utiliser *papier* : de manière formelle à ma connaissance pas pour l'[*article*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871273) [scientifique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361076) ni pour le *[travail de](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871730) (fin de) session*, l'[épreuve](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/paper/600246) etc. ; pour l'*article de journal* c'est [possible](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/papier)...

Answer (score 0):

Traduire « seminal » par « fondateur » me semble être une erreur lorsque l'on se réfère à la définition du mot « fondateur »; il n'exite qu'un fondateur de la mécanique de Newton, qu'un fondateur des théories de la relativité, qu'un fondateur de l'intégrale de Riemann et qu'un fondateur de l'intégrale de Lebesgue. De même, il n'existe qu'un papier fondateur de ces théories, le premier, celui qui forge les premiers  nouveaux concepts de la base de la théorie, ces concepts qui constituent l'essentiel. Il est regrettable que l'on dissocie le terme « fondateur » ainsi du contexte générique auquel il est associé de par son emploi pour référer à un (ou rarement deux) scientifiques que l'on reconnait comme le seul responsable pour une idée nouvelle. Ce qui en anglais est appelé « the father (of relativity/modern science/etc.) » n'est pas autre chose que le fondateur en français.  Il y a bien dans le mot anglais « seminal » l'idée de l'élément initiateur, de l'élément premier responsable d'un nouveau départ mais cela n'est que relatif; l'initiateur est encore le porteur de ce sperme, lequel peut être regardé simplement tel qu'un symbole de fécondité; de plus le point de vue anglo-saxon n'est pas nécessairement idéal; apparemment on ne trouve pas de termes consacrés anglais qui permettent de dissocier les deux sortes d'article dont il est question alors qu'existe le terme nécessaire à discriminer parmi les mérites respectifs des divers contributeurs; pourquoi adhérer à un point de vue rendant flous les mérites comparés alors que l'on peut facilement introduire une discrimination utile. La définition de « seminal article » ou « seminal paper » est « article très important et ayant une grande influence sur les développements ultérieurs »; il n'est pas impliqué par cela qu'il s'agisse des pierres angulaires d'une théorie et pourtant c'est le terme à utiliser en référence à ces articles primordiaux. Est-ce qu'il va falloir appeler le travail d'un Michelson et d'un Morley qui ont apporté la première vérification de la théorie restreinte de la relativité un travail fondateur dans la théorie? Il est indubitable que ce travail a été très important et qu'il a eu une grande influence dans les développements, mais pas plus.
En traduction de cette seconde sorte d'article la meilleure possibilité en termes existants reste « article fécond », mais des possibilités plus intéressantes pourraient être considérées.

Comment: Vos remarques ont été prises en compte dans ma réponse.