# What's the word for "a paper" that you do at university?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What's the French word for a *paper* - as in a short piece of writing on a particular subject done by students? Is it *l'article*, *l'exposé* or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a complement to Nino Filiu's. There are contexts  relevant today as concerns the use of the word in learned circles.  « Thèse »   seems to be the central term, and « article » a recent adjonction to the vocabulary. The term « **article de recherche** » is mentionned in this article: [*La méthodologie universitaire : forme et contenu*](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00699918/document).

- scientific **paper**: **étude, mémoire**

Dans le milieu universitaire, une thèse est un mémoire résumant un travail de recherche universitaire. (Wikipédia)

Dans les pays francophones, la thèse représente un travail de recherche de plus grande ampleur que le mémoire. Au Royaume-Uni, le terme de thèse (thesis) est utilisé pour les travaux de doctorat et de master recherche, les masters professionnels et les bachelors étant obtenus après rédaction d'une dissertation. Aux États-Unis, le terme de dissertation est employé plus largement que celui de thesis. Dans certaines universités, le terme de thesis est même limité aux travaux du niveau du master. (Wikipédia)

- He did a good **paper** in French.: *Il a fait un bon **écrit** en français.*

**Mostly post-university use** (I'd say)

- to read a **paper** **(i)** *faire une **communication** (à une société savante, etc.) **(ii)** faire une **conférence**, un **exposé**; colloquial: lire un **papier**

Answer (score 7):

Whenever it is possible to say *a paper* in English, *une publication* is the correct translation.

For more precise usages, consider:

- *Un article*: publication in a journal
- *Une thèse*: same as English's [thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis)

NB: **Don't say *un papier*! It litterally means *a paper*, as in, a sheet of paper...**

Comment: In American English, a "paper" doesn't get necessarily published; so, most of time, "une publication" wouldn't be an acceptable translation.

Answer (score 2):

Quand on parle d'un "paper" en milieu universitaire, on parle ni d'une "thèse" ni d'un "article" publié dans une revue. On parle ou (a) d'un "exposé" que l'étudiant remettra dans un cours à la fin de la session ou (b) d'une communication qu'on présentera ou qu'on a déjà présentée à un congrès, symposium ou autre rencontre. À un niveau très informel, on utilise "paper" [pépèr] à tour de bras. À noter que dans les cours où on demande à l'étudiant de présenter un paper pour la session, il n'y a généralement pas d'examen de fin de session (final exam). Sur ce dernier point, je parle pour la situation au Québec.

Comment: Voir aussi incidemment [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32690/3177). Merci !

Comment: Est-ce que le mot "traité" est aussi possible ?

Comment: @lmc "traité" corresponds exactly to "treatise".

Comment: @LPH Alors est-ce que vous employez ce mot ? Je n'ai jamais entendu treatise en anglais, mais l'anglais n'est pas ma langue maternelle quand même...

Comment: @lmc Pas exactement à "l'université des étudiants"; un traité est un livre (presque toujours) et qui entreprend de faire le point sur un sujet très important dans un détail souvent assez considérable; ce sont des ouvrages qu'il n'est pas donné aux étudiants d'écrire, en général, vu leur connaissances limitées et vu le temps que ces travaux demandent et ils sont donc écrits par des professeurs des universités. On peut écrire un traité sur la mécanique de Newton, par exemple ou sur un insecte, comme l'abeille, etc.

Comment: @LPH D'accord, merci !