# La distinction entre les types d'articles académiques

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, académique

Dans le monde académique anglophone, on distingue plusieurs types d'articles:

- *journal paper* (généralement, un article de recherche dans un journal spécialisé)
- *magazine paper* (un article de recherche dans une parution pour grand public)
- *extended conference paper/abstract* (article présenté lors d'une conférence, généralement de 2 à 5 pages)
- *conference abstract* (petit article composé de seulement d'un petit nombre de paragraphes)

Ce n'est peut-être pas complet, mais c'est la catégorisation habituelle dans mon domaine.
J'ai regardé [What's the word for "a paper" that you do at university?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33361/26527), mais je recherche plus de détails sur les noms des différents types d'article correspondant aux termes anglais.

Y a-t-il des termes couramment utilisés en français qui permettent de faire la distinction entre les divers types d'articles académiques  ?

Utilisation prévue : traduire la partie suivante du CV (pour la recherche universitaire ou industrielle):

> Full list of publications: 1 book chapter, 2 magazine papers, 10 journal papers, 13 extended conference papers, and 24 conference abstracts.

- Domaine: l'ingénierie
- Région: Québec, France, Belgique, Suisse (c'est un peu large, donc probablement quelque chose de général, pas trop spécifique à une région donnée)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ca dépend de tellement de choses : quelle région de la francophonie ? Quel pan du système académique ou de recherche ? Quelle discipline ? Par exemple, l'expression "de congrès" donnée par Segorian n'a pas de sens dans les champs où on ne fait pas de congrès mais autre chose : des conférences, des colloques...

Comment: @guillaume31 ajouté. en général, j'ai besoin d'avoir une version de mon CV en français et je cherche la meilleure façon de formuler certaines choses qui soient aussi générales que possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les termes suivants sont d'usage assez courant :

> *book chapter* : **chapitre d'ouvrage**
> *journal paper* : **article de recherche** (également : article (ou publication) scientifique)
> *magazine paper* : **article de vulgarisation** (également : article (ou publication) grand public)
> *conference abstract* : **résumé de congrès**
> *conference paper* : **communication de congrès**

En ce qui concerne « extended conference paper », ce terme signifie souvent, si je ne me trompe, une communication de congrès qui a été remaniée et augmentée pour être publiée dans une revue scientifique. En ce moment, je ne me souviens pas d'un terme spécifique pour cela en français.

Voir aussi le tableau ci-dessous, que vous retrouverez dans [ce document](https://coop-ist.cirad.fr/content/download/4675/35073/version/3/file/5+questions+%C3%A0+se+poser+avant+de+publier.pdf).

[image: Termes utilisés pour les différents publications scientifiques]